# click through a series of questions using Selenium -- can't get past the first

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Selenium w/ Python to click through a series of questions on a testing website.  For now, it doesn't matter which answer is selected - I just want to be able to get from one question to the next.  Here's what I have so far:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="../../geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.varsitytutors.com/practice-tests')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# click subject
subject=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]')))
subject.click()
# select specialty
specialty=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[4]')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[4]')))
specialty.click()
# select test
taketest=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[8]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", taketest)
wait.until(EC.url_contains('diagnostic'))
driver.get(driver.current_url.replace('http', 'https'))

# click away popup
button=WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'No Thanks')]")))
button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
button.click()

# select first choice
choice=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[7]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/form/input[1]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", choice)
```

This last command does what it's supposed to do.  As far as I know, the next command should do the same thing -- click the first answer on the next question...

```
# select first choice again
choice=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[7]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/form/input[1]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", choice)
```

This doesn't work, however.  The connection is lost and a Firefox error page comes up.

My goal is to click through the entire series of questions in this particular test.  Can anyone help me figure out what to do?

Comment: please post the html source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `infinite` `while` loop and provide `Try`..`Except` block to check choices are there then click otherwise go to exception block and exit.Try below code.I haven't tested all question however the loop working fine.Let me know how it goes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="../../geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.varsitytutors.com/practice-tests')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# click subject
subject=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-subject='ACT']/div[1]")))
subject.click()
# select specialty
specialty=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-subject='ACT English']//div[@class='expandable']//a[contains(.,'Practice Tests')]")))
specialty.click()
# select test
taketest=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//h3[text()='ACT English Diagnostic Test 1']/following::div[1]/a[1]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", taketest)

# click away popup
button=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'No Thanks')]")))
button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
button.click()

# select any choice
while True:
   try:
     choice=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.test_button")))
     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", choice[3])
     time.sleep(3)
   except:
     break
```